# curling ESP8265 status Is:no such file or directory

Tags: curl, nginx, webserver, macos

I'm on OSX Mojave 10.14.6
I'm a trying to flash a newer firmware via OTA on an ESP8265 SoC embedded on a smart switch. 
I created a network with specific SSID and PSW. The ESP is connected to the network.
I'm running in background NGINX web server for Range request header support.

I am trying now to retrive its status with this line command:

```
curl http://<deviceIP>:8081/zeroconf/signal_strength -XPOST --data '{"deviceID":"<deviceID>","data":{} }'
```

I swapped  with the current IP address of the device, taken from the admin backend of the router.

I am getting

```
-bash: 192.168.1.117: No such file or directory
```

I also tried leaving  but the result is the same:

```
-bash: deviceIP: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the exact commands you are running?

Comment: I used curl http://<deviceIP>:8081/zeroconf/signal_strength -XPOST --data '{"deviceID":"<deviceID>","data":{} }'

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to leave the `<` and `>` symbols in, they are there to annotate that you need to replace that string.  When left in bash is treating them as [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) operators.

You are using the command:

```
curl http://<192.168.1.117>:8081/zeroconf/signal_strength -XPOST --data '{"deviceID":"<deviceID>","data":{} }'
```

But you should have changed it to:

```
curl http://192.168.1.117:8081/zeroconf/signal_strength -XPOST --data '{"deviceID":"<deviceID>","data":{} }'
```

You also need to replace `<deviceID>` in the json payload.

As far as:

```
http://<deviceIP>:8081/zeroconf/signal_strength -XPOST --data '{"deviceID":"<deviceID>","data":{} }'
```

I feel it's pretty self-explanatory why that fails.